# How to combine two probabilities for the same event? Context: error correction codes / decoding

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability, statistical-inference

I'm learning the maths behind error correction codes. For this purpose I made this question for myself:

Assume there are two random bits $x_0$, $x_1$, which are both i.i.d. and have a 50% chance of being 0 or 1 (the information bits) and an additional check bit $x_2 = x_0 \mathbin{\mathsf{XOR}} x_1$). You now transfer all 3 bits through an additive white gaussian noise channel (AWGNC), one by one. The AWGNC adds noise to each bit independently and on the receiver side, you can only restore each bit with some probability, depending on what you received. You do this for each bit individually and independently of the other bits and conclude that the 3 probabilities of the bits to be 1 are $p = (0.2, 0.9, 0.7)$, I.e.

$P(x_0 = 1 \;|\; \text{given the noisy version of $x_0$ that you received}) = 0.2$
$P(x_1 = 1 \;|\; \text{given the noisy version of $x_1$ that you 
received}) = 0.9$
$P(x_2 = 1 \;|\; \text{given the noisy version of $x_2$ that you received}) = 0.7$

Obviously, the best guess $y$ for the sent bits $x$ is $y = (0, 1, 1)$. How to calculate the combined probability of this guess to be correct? Or of any other guess? I.e. how to calculate $P(x = (0, 1, 1) \;|\; p = (0.2, 0.9, 0.7))$ or other guesses?

Using the fact that the originally sent $x_2$ is the XOR of the other two originally sent bits, we can use the probabilities $p_0$ and $p_1$ to infer another probability about $x_2$:

$$
\begin{align}
p_2' := {} &P(x_2 = 1 \mid p_0 = 0.2, p_1 = 0.9) \\[4pt]
= {} & P(x_0 = 0 \mid p_0 = 0.2) \cdot P(x_1 = 1 \mid p_1 = 0.9) \\
 {} & + P(x_0 = 1 \mid p_0 = 0.2) \cdot P(x_1 = 0 \mid p_1 = 0.9)\\[4pt]
= {} & (1 - 0.2) \cdot 0.9 + 0.2 \cdot (1 - 0.9) \\[4pt]
= {} & 0.8 \cdot 0.9 + 0.2 \cdot 0.1\\[4pt]
= {} & 0.72 + 0.02\\[4pt]
= {} & 0.74.
\end{align}
$$

How to combine the probabilities $p_2' = 0.74$ and $p_2 = 0.7$ into the combined probability $p_2'' := P(x_2 = 1  \;|\; p = (0.2, 0.9, 0.7))$?

Does the question make sense in this form? Do I need to know the distribution of the probability after the channel, given a bit's value before the channel?

To give an illustration and overview of the relations for transferring a single bit b:

[image: illustration and overview of the relations]

Comment: It seems like you should consider each of the four possible two-bit messages and apply something like Bayes' rule.

Comment: I think you need to say something about what you mean by “the probabilities of each bit to be $1$”. The sent bits are not random variables, so they’re not naturally associated with a probability. I suspect that you mean something like “if random bits with equal and independent *a priori* probability to be $0$ or $1$ had been sent, the received information would yield *a posteriori* probabilities $(0.2,0.9,0.7)$ for these bits to be $1$”?

Comment: @joriki Thanks for the hint. I edited the question. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @Karl I thought so, too, but I walk in cycles if I do this, because all the bits' combined probabilities depend on each others' probabilities.

Comment: I think a simple reasonable approach is to treat the decoder's output as defining a probability measure on the space of all 3-bit messages. Then you can just compute the conditional probability $P(011|\{000,011,101,110\})$, i.e. condition on your knowledge of the checksum property.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate all 4 possibilities for the correct values of $x$.  Apply Bayes rule.

Let $x=(x_0,x_1,x_2)$ denote the true values.  Let $\tilde{x}=(\tilde{x}_0,\tilde{x}_1,\tilde{x}_2)$ denote the observed values.  There are four possibilities for $x$, i.e., 000, 011, 101, 110.  You know the prior on $x$, i.e., you can compute the probabilities $\Pr[x=abc]$ for each possible $abc$: specifically, for each $abc \in \{000,011,101,110\}$, you have $\Pr[x=abc] = 1/4$.  You also have a model for the channel (based on the parameters of the AWGNC), i.e., you are given

$$q_i = p(\tilde{x}_i=d | x_i=a)$$

where $p(\cdot | x_i=a)$ is the pdf of $\tilde{x}_i$, conditioned on $x_i=a$.

Finally, your goal is to compute

$$\Pr[x = abc | \tilde{x} = def],$$

where $def$ are the observed values of $\tilde{x}$ and $abc$ are the hypothesized/inferred values of $x$.  This conditional probability can be computed with Bayes rule, i.e.,

$$\Pr[x = abc | \tilde{x} = def] =
{p(\tilde{x}=def | x=abc) \Pr[x=abc]
\over \sum_{a'b'c'} p(\tilde{x}=def | x=a'b'c') \Pr[x=a'b'c']}.
$$

Notice that your independence assumption tells you that

$$p(\tilde{x}=def | x=abc) = p(\tilde{x}_0=d | x_0=a) \cdot p(\tilde{x}_1=e | x_1=b) \cdot p(\tilde{x}_2=f | x_0=c).$$

As a result, all of the terms in the RHS of Bayes rule can be computed with the information given to you.  This lets you compute the conditional probability that was your goal.

Work through an example to see this in action.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Much appreciated, esp. the explanations! Had just a glance though and it looks like what I need.  I'll accept it after working through it and finding what I needed.

Comment: I think the $q_i = Pr[\tilde{x} = d \;|\; x = a]$ here are 0, because they are probabilities for the event that a continuously distributed variable $\tilde{x}$ hits one given value out of infinitely many possible values. Do you mean the other way around, i.e. $Pr[x = a \;|\; \tilde{x} = d]$? The latter one is > 0, because there are only two possibilities for x. (see newly added plot in question)

Comment: @DanielS., oh, good catch!  I missed that $\tilde{x}$ is continuous.  See edited answer.  I have replaced $\Pr[...]$ with $p(...)$ (pdf).